# SQL, Selecting between date/times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, time, between

This is for (MS SQL Server 2008) It allows the user to schedule other users for a start and end date/time without overlaps.

I'm addressing the business rule of not being able to overlap individuals during a schedule. E.G, If user 1 is scheduled from 1/1/2012 to 1/4/2012, user 2 should not be able to submit a request for 1/2/2012 to 1/4/2012. This part is already taken care of, and here is my SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM fooTable
WHERE
    Prim = 1
AND 
    Group = 10
AND
    (('2012-06-01 08:01' between startdate and enddate
   OR '2012-06-03 08:01' between startdate and enddate)
OR
   ('2012-06-01 08:01' < startdate) AND ('2012-06-03 8:01' > enddate))
```

I now have a requirement to allow a schedule to overlap in the sense that the new shift can begin as the last one ends. E.G, My end date is 1/1/2012 at 8:00pm - I should be able to schedule someone to start at 1/1/2012 and 8:00pm.

Need some help thinking this one through.

Comment: This is often database specific and should really be tagged with the specific RDBMS you're using - Oracle, MySQL etc. You're not converting your dates explicitly, which you really should be.

Comment: Shouldn't the same logic work if you are storing the full date/time for start and end, and comparing them?  A start time of `1/1/2012 20:00` shouldn't overlap an end time of `1/1/2012 20:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't use `Group` as a column name. It is a reserved word in every SQL standard. I renamed it to `grp` for the purpose of my answer.

Trying to schedule a new shift from `'2012-06-01 08:00'` to `'2012-06-03 08:00'` ...

```
INSERT INTO tbl (prim, grp, startdate, enddate)
SELECT 1, 10, '2012-06-01 08:00', '2012-06-03 08:00'
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  prim = 1
    AND    grp = 10
    AND   '2012-06-03 08:00' > startdate -- not >= to allow sharing a border
    AND   '2012-06-01 08:00' < enddate   -- and not BETWEEN ... AND either
    )
```

Note that I compare:

```
new_end   > old_start
new_start < old_end
```

If you use `BETWEEN .. AND ..` you include the borders of a shift in your test. It's the same as using `>=` and `<=`. You need to use `>` and `<` to allow borders to overlap.

Well, and try my largely simplified syntax. Not sure about what you had there originally.
Here is a [working demo on sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56fb5/1) to play with.

Comment: Also, consider the case where the there's a record in the DB with a start of 1/1/2012 and an end of 1/7/2012 - if I submit a new one with 12/31/2011 and 1/8/2012, it should still error saying someone already is covering that schedule. I have that part built in my query, that's why I had the second OR statement.

Comment: @JasonWells: My query does that. Try it! It should cover all overlapping cases. If you cannot combine the `SELECT` with the `INSERT` just take the `SELECT` from my answer.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks - I am still having issues though :( - http://pastebin.com/uRb6Zepc- My query (the top one), returns one result which it should, where as yours does not. Perhaps my syntax is wacky?

Comment: @JasonWells: Your link doesn't seem to work. The logic of my query should be sound, I have been using it for years. Assumes that all columns are `NOT NULL`, btw. Take a piece of paper and use overlapping lines to visualize. Helps me, when I get confused. Your syntax does something similar, but not *exactly* what you asked for. There are corner cases ... should be easy to verify.

Comment: @JasonWells: The link works now. You got it **backwards** in your example (start - start, end - end). I added a bit to may answer that should clarify the logic.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, 

My confusion was that I didn't notice you actually are using the start date variable against the enddate column. I switched this around and I believe it's working properly now. Thanks again.