# Mysql: checking range time conflicts

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following table where teachers class routine are stored

Table Name: batchroutine_regular

```
batchid class_day   subject    teacherid class_start   class_end
   1     Sunday     English-1    1001     02:00 PM     03:30 PM
   1     Sunday     Geography    1002     04:00 PM     05:30 PM
   2     Monday     Math         1001     10:00 AM     12:30 PM
   2     Tuesday    Geography    1001     01:00 PM     03:30 PM
```

Now lets say you are the teacher whose `teacherid` is `1001`. You are asked to take a class on Monday which will start at `11:00 AM` and end at `1:00 PM`. Now my question is what would be the MYSQL/PHP query to find out if you are available at that time, from the table `batchroutine_regular`?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Check this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289675/query-for-a-list-of-multiple-day-events-occurring-between-today-and-one-week-fro). Also this question, [answered by @Erwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286561/sql-selecting-between-date-times/10286959#10286959)

Comment: Are `class_start` and `class_end` time fields? Strings? What datatype?

Comment: @Thanks Nick, class_start and class_end both are varchar, not time fields. Sorry, I should have mentioned it. :) thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = 0) AS Available
FROM batchroutine_regular
WHERE
      teacherid = 1001
  AND class_day = 'Sunday'
  AND (
       (class_start <= MAKETIME(11,00,00) AND class_end >= MAKETIME(11,00,00))
    OR (class_start <= MAKETIME(13,00,00) AND class_end >= MAKETIME(13,00,00))
  )
```

Comment: @ eggyal Thanks for your reply. I have tried your code but its not working.. it is always showing the Available value as "1" not matter what. Could you please kindly recheck your code. Thanks again.:)

Comment: Given your latest comment above, you might consider changing the data type of the `class_start` and `class_end` columns to [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html)

Comment: @ eggyal. I have changed the data type to TIME but still its not working. When I changed the data type to TIME the value of my `class_start` and `class_end` columns got changed.. like this-- 02:00 AM got changed to 02:00:00. Would you please help me to find out the problem?

Comment: @Srijon: Unless I'm very much mistaken 02:00:00 **is** 02:00 AM, is it not?  Did your afternoon times get changed to morning ones too?  If so, you'll have to manually update them to afternoon again; if you have a column containing the original data, you could do something like `UPDATE batchroutine_regular SET class_start = ADDTIME(class_start, MAKETIME(12,00,00)) WHERE old_class_start LIKE '% PM';`

Comment: @ eggyal: YEs 02:00:00 is 02:00 AM. The data I had in my table was exactly like in my post above. After I have changed the data type to time 02:00 AM got changed to 02:00:00, 03:30 PM to 03:00:00 ..like this.. just `00` got replaced in place of AM/PM. Please tell me what should I do now?

Comment: If the table shown in your question was complete, run these commands: `UPDATE batchroutine_regular SET class_start = ADDTIME(class_start, MAKETIME(12,00,00)), class_end = ADDTIME(class_end, MAKETIME(12,00,00)) WHERE NOT (teacherid = 1001 AND batchid = 2); UPDATE batchroutine_regular SET class_end = MAKETIME(12,30,00) WHERE teacherid = 1001 AND batchid = 2;`

Comment: @ eggyal I have run the command you posted and then I tried your solution but still its showing `1` as a value of `Available`. Please check this link to see how my table is looking like after I run your command. http://i40.tinypic.com/5ldl6o.jpg And just for your information my table storage engine is InnoDB. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, my oversight - you still need to update the `class_start` time in the fourth row: `UPDATE bathroutine_regular SET class_start = MAKETIME(13,00,00) WHERE batchid = 2 AND class_day = 'Tuesday';`.  And you're running the command exactly as above?  Or some modified version thereof?

Comment: Okay, I have updated it. I tried the script again but still now luck. Here's the complete picture of what I am doing> http://i39.tinypic.com/1z36jur.jpg :) thanks :)

Comment: Indeed, the you are getting a result of `1` because the teacher is available during the specified hours; if you change the day/times to a cover a period in which they are not available, you will get a `0`.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43dfe/11

Comment: Sorry mistake. its working now. thanks a lot. :)